Is Foundation necessary to prove the equivalence of limitation of size with the existence of a surjection from On into the universal class?
Working in the NBG set theory with only local choice axiom and without the axiom of Foundation,is it possible to prove that the existence of a surjection from the class On of all ordinals onto the universal class U of all sets is equivalent with the principle of limitation of size (that every proper class is bijective with U)?

You don't even need the "local choice axiom" - if U is bijective to On, then any proper class is bijective with a subclass of On, and any proper subclass of On is in bijection with On itself.
